# Explicit conversion of date to character

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on MySQL workbench 6.0 and I want to convert a date column values to character column but I am getting syntax error when I use convert() function.
for example:

```
select convert(char, last_update, 120) from sakila.actor;
```

here actor is a table name, and last_update is column containg timestamp values

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server database?

Comment: What is the error message that you are getting?

Comment: it's MySQL database and error message is: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' last_update, 101) from sakila.actor' at line 1 0.000 sec

Comment: Why do you think Microsoft SQL Server specific functions will work with MySQL? there is no mentioning of a `convert` function in the MySQL manual.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you use MySQL (Workbench 6.0) and try to use a MSSQL function. But the functions and syntax are different for every DB engine.

Use the MySQL [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function to generate the output you like.

Comment: hi, actually I want to convert the date column values to character values and display the results in a particuar format... is it possible?

Comment: Yes, look at the link in my answer